# Webpage validation, how to escape string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On a website to create requests I have a problem when the user enters his request in a multiline textbox.
This text can be something like a description on how to use LDAPserver and the webserver then validates the page as unsafe.

For now I have switched of validation, but I rather keep it on.
The text is stored in to a database field and besides showing it in a textbox nothing is done with it. (the person who processes it, reads it and does his thing).

Is there a way to escape this text so it would pass the validation?

rg.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below post for your multiline textbox to continue work with the validation

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/407250/A-tiny-Javascript-framework-for-common-validation